# In root LinearLayout android:gravity="center" shows padding

Tags: android

when I remove gravity attribute then the image will set on top corner right but when it used it leave padding at the top why gravity leaves space ????
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUL0U.png)

Comment: Did you test it on actual device or an emulator?

Comment: It is not showing you padding it shows your layout  in center

Comment: @AbhayBohra yes

Comment: @Aj27 yes it shows center but it also takes some space on the top see in my uploaded image

Comment: it is not showing space on top just change it to center_horizontal you will get idea.

Comment: post your xml code

Answer (score 0):

```
android:gravity="center"  ---> center_horizontal+center_vertical
```

The **center_vertical** attribute leaves the padding at the top. Changing it to center_horizontal will make the view/views *just align* center horizontally so use

```
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think why should you use layout_marginTop in imageview?it's not necessory to set.you can set layout_gravity at imageview and remove gravity at top linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/android_ic"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you have added `android:gravity="center"` your entire layout will be at center of the screen.Since you have added multiple views below the `imageView`, it has been managed to be at the top with some space.Change it to `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` and also if the image is small set the height as "wrap_content" instead of 200dp ,it may also have additional space.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:src="@drawable/coffee"
    /></LinearLayout>
```